# Accepting a job offer out of fear of not finding anything better?

Tags: job-search

I'm currently studying my M.Sc. in computer science and will be done with it in a bit more than two months. I got a job offer from a big and well-known company, but the position is not really related to things I'd like to do, and I don't even have a good understanding of what I would need to do there. My potential boss is aware of this, but he liked my performance during the interviews and he believes I'll learn and be a good fit in their team.

I don't have any other offers, because I applied to a small number of companies, got rejected by most of them and still waiting for a reply from one company where I got to the final round.

I'm afraid I won't find anything better, and I don't want to end up being unemployed after finishing university. So I'm inclined to accept the offer. However, I'm not sure if this experience would help me to find a job later in the area where I want to work. I also don't want to just work there for a few months until I find another job, because that's a bit unprofessional.

I can't decide what to do: Should I accept this offer and hope that I'll either like the job or will at least gain some experience? Or should I keep searching for something in my area, although there is not a lot of time left?

Comment: The answer heavily depends on how happy you think you'll be there, how difficult it would be for you to find what you're actually looking for and whether you can survive a month or three without a salary. Those are unfortunately not things we can really know. Although working at a big well-known company would hardly look bad on your resume, and you probably shouldn't expect to find your dream job straight out of university.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would definitely take it, for the following reasons:

1. You might find that you enjoy it more than you think, or you really like the people you are working with, and so might want to stay anyway.
2. It will take the pressure off of job searching. There is nothing worse than having to look for a job when you are not employed, and you have the added pressure that you can't afford (financially) to not get it. This way, you will at least be earning and you will be able to take more time to find the 'perfect' job that you really want and you won't have the pressure of being desperate (so you might be more relaxed in interviews).
3. Any job experience is good experience and will enhance your resume. Even if some of the work is not directly related to your ideal job, you will gain many transferable skills (e.g. team working, time management, presentation), which can be applied to just about any job. You will also find yourself dealing with real job situations, which you can then talk about in interviews and will make you a stronger candidate.

I wouldn't be concerned about getting 'pigeon-holed' into that area, if you are only there for 6 months to a year. That might possibly be a concern if you stayed in the same type of position for 5+ years.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with carrying on your search for the ideal job, once you are employed. I don't think most people would consider that 'unprofessional' at all. It is not at all uncommon for someone to start a new job and find that is isn't a good fit (for a myriad of possible reasons), or to find that something better comes along soon after.