# Accept current job offer or wait for future offer?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, united-states

I am completing my undergraduate teaching degree this April. I currently student teach at an elementary school and have received a verbal job offer. My fiance and I are moving to another city about an hour away. I don't want to do the commute and I am not very excited for the grade I would be teaching (5th grade... I would really like to teach lower elementary), but I'm scared I won't find anything better.

What would be the pros and cons of accepting this offer or waiting and search for something better in the city we are moving to?

I looked for duplicate questions and [this question is close](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/115876/accepting-a-job-offer-out-of-fear-of-not-finding-anything-better?newreg=f0f9d356465a45dca49557b3dcbbd526), but doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: Have you tried searching for opportunities on the city you are moving to yet? If not perhaps you should to be able to make a better choice

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yeah. Most of the time teaching positions for the following school year are posted in May. I have until Friday to accept or decline my offer.

Comment: is the verbal offer to start immediately, or is it for a position that starts next school year? If it starts immediately what is the end date?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep It would be around April 8th (before I graduate). Not sure the end date but would guess it would be the following school year (late Spring 2021)

Comment: The question asks us to make a prediction about which of two choices will be better in the future. We are unable to predict the future; maybe this job that you're worried about will turn out to be awesome, or maybe it will be horrible. Maybe there's a better job that you could get right away, or maybe you won't find anything for a long time. **We don't know. We cannot predict the future**.

Comment: I realize that this question is closed, but the world is heading to a (possibly) severe recession due to the COVID-19 virus. Take the first job you are offered.

Answer (score 2):

Objectively speaking. It would be better for you to arrive to your new city with a job already secured, instead of getting there without one and *then* start looking for a job.

Relocating to a new country/city is not a trivial process, and usually means that you have to manage several details and aspects that come along with relocating. Many of those things that come with relocating usually cost money (moving your stuff, new bills, paperwork, etc.), not to mention your valuable time.

Relocating to a new country/city, without having a job secured already, will surely make the process harder.

Comment: I upvoted, but think this doesn't quite answer my question of accepting such a long commute versus waiting for another opportunity come the summer. Some additional information: my fiance currently lives and works in that city. He's a data scientist for one of the larger companies there and he'll be handling most of the moving logistics. The biggest issue I'm running into is that schools usually don't post job listings until May, while I need to answer by Friday.

Comment: @wrkplc_tchr this is just my grain of sand to help. Surely more users will add their suggestions and answers soon :)

Comment: Thanks for the input! I do appreciate the thoughts :)

Comment: @wrkplc_tchr just to clarify (seems I didn't get it quite right). The offer you got is for your current city? Or is it for the city you are moving to?

Comment: The offer is for the current city, not the one we are moving to.

Answer (score 1):

**Pros of accepting current offer**

1. You have a job.  Money is good.
2. It's done.  You can focus on your move, goof off, hike the Appalachian Trail, etc.
3. You know what the school is like and who your co-workers and bosses will be.
4. This *might* be the best job available to you.

**Cons of accepting current offer**

1. 1 hour commute
2. Not your preferred grade
3. You *might* be missing out on a better paying or more favorable position

Only you can provide the appropriate weight to each item.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically taking a bet.

Let's say you plan to stay at one place for three years. That's 36 months of salaries, commute etc.

If you look 3 months for a job, without pay, you need to make the same money in 33 months to be even. So let's say you can get $3,300 a month today, then you need $3,600 a month in three months time, to draw even. If you get the $3,600 a month next month, you won. If you wait 3 months and don't get more money, you lost.

Look at interviews that you had. How well did you do? How confident are you to find something better? (Some people have low confidence. How confident are your friends that you will find something better? ) How stressful do you find looking for a job?

So you need to weigh the different factors and decide based on that. An important question is: At what point will you be in financial difficulties? And in that case, will you be able to get a different job that is *not* better to minimise damages?